# Crash at startup on port to Cordova Crosswalk (Android)

Tags: android, cordova

I'm porting an existing android cordova app to cordova crosswalk.

Using cordova 4, crosswalk-cordova-10.39.235.9-x86 and Android SDK 19

The app crashes at startup with the following logs in logcat:

`D/AndroidRuntime( 7208): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 7208): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41caeda0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208): Process: myapp.cqa, PID: 7208
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebView(CordovaActivity.java:295)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:348)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:323)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at myapp.cqa.CordovaApp.onCreate(CordovaApp.java:31)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Use SharedXWalkView if you want to support shared mode
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.handleException(ReflectionHelper.java:233)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.handleException(ReflectionHelper.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.init(ReflectionHelper.java:132)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at org.xwalk.core.ReflectionHelper.loadClass(ReflectionHelper.java:199)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.java:112)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.<clinit>(CordovaWebView.java:890)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    ... 18 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Use SharedXWalkView if you want to support shared mode
E/AndroidRuntime( 7208):    ... 23 more`

Any idea why it crashes ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, after a night of sleeping, I realized I was using x86 crosswalk instead of the ARM one. Sorry for the dumb issue post...